# MSMQ works on TCP or UDP?

Tags: tcp, udp, msmq

i want to know that MSMQ (Microsoft Messaging Queue) works on TCP or UDP?? and on what ports?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This KB details which ports and protocols are used: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;178517

> The following ports are used for
>   Microsoft Message Queuing operations:
>   TCP: 1801 RPC: 135, 2101*, 2103*,
>   2105* UDP: 3527, 1801 The following is
>   new for Message Queuing 3.0:
>
> While Message Queuing uses the same
>   ports that are used in earlier
>   versions of the product, Message
>   Queuing also introduces TCP port 389.
>   TCP port 389 has to be open for MQIS
>   queries that are made directly against
>   Active Directory. Additionally,
>   Message Queuing 3.0 introduces HTTP
>   Messaging that requires that the port
>   that is specified for the Message
>   Queuing virtual directory be open
>   also.
>
> This information is useful for
>   interpreting the following: Netstat -a
>   output A network trace Configuring a
>   firewall

Answer (score 0):

The currently accepted answer redirects to a link that is no longer available. The link has been superseded with a new support redesign.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/service-overview-and-network-port-requirements#message-queuing

Which provides documentation for all MSMQ from Windows 7 Service Pack 1 to Server 2019.

To not just provide an answer without meaningful information and to properly bring information here for the future admins who have to deal with this...

| Application protocol | Protocol | Ports |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MSMQ | TCP | 1801 |
| MSMQ | UDP | 1801 |
| MSMQ-DCs | TCP | 2101 |
| MSMQ-Mgmt | TCP | 2107 |
| MSMQ-Ping | UDP | 3527 |
| MSMQ-RPC | TCP | 2105 |
| MSMQ-RPC | TCP | 2103 |
| RPC | TCP | 135 |

May it serve you well